# Power BI How to avoid sum of created measure

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a database contains "Company Names","Purchase Order","Payment Amount". data preview image is below
[image]

I try to create matrix table with columns;

Company name: Returns company names, that' s OK

Hk: at how many times I have pay that company, **at this point i have a problem**

SUM_Payment: sums all payments, that' s ok, see matrix table image below;
[image]

My expectation from matrix table is **"Not to see sum of Hk"** . How can I avoid summing **Hk** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one

```
Hk =
IF(
    ISFILTERED( Hakedis_Data[Company_name] ),
    MAX( Hakedis_Data[Purchase Order] ),
    BLANK()
)
```